# can I have a BLE device (maybe an app on mac) pair with iphone bluetooth without an app on the phone

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, bluetooth

I want to write an OSX app (about bluetooth keyboard) use bluetooth to control my iphone. so my mac act as a bluetooth keyboard. I do know there are several softwares to do this, but I still want to know how to make it. I can't discover my macbook bluetooth in the iphone system bluetooth menu.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, pairing is a feature of Bluetooth 1.0, not BLE. Bluetooth keyboards and such use Bluetooth 1.0, which requires pairing.

BLE is a simpler, low power API that does not require pairing. It involves advertising and subscribing to "services".

Apple requires you to sign up for a separate SDK in order to develop "old school" Bluetooth devices like keyboards and headsets that pair with their hardware.